# change bootstrap date range picker's lables dynamically according to the selected language in cookie

Tags: javascript, cookies, bootstrap-daterangepicker

I want to change date range picker's labels according to the language locale cookie which is set by user side. Right now, by default, I am using English labels, which I want to change them according to the cookie.

```
    var locale = $.cookie('locale');
    moment.locale(locale);
    var start = moment();
    var end = moment().add(29, 'days');

    $('#Date').daterangepicker({
        startDate: start,
        endDate: end,
        autoUpdateInput: false,
        locale: {
            cancelLabel: 'Clear'
        },
        ranges: {
            'Today': [moment(), moment()],
            'Tomorrow': [moment().add(1, 'days'), moment().add(1, 'days')],
            'Next 7 Days': [moment(), moment().add(6, 'days')],
            'Next 30 Days': [moment(), moment().add(29, 'days')],
            'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
            'Next Month': [moment().add(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().add(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
        },
        "alwaysShowCalendars": true
    });
```

using `moment.locale('custom language')` helped to have the names of dates and month in localized language, but, how can I customize the labels of `Today`, `Tomorrow` and the others?

I want to get just the language id like 'en', 'fr' or others from cookie and then change the attributes in my javascript code according to that.

Answer (score 1):

You should edit your locale object as below. Add "Apply" and "Cancel" on your cookie in desired language. Read from cookie and place them as I did below.

```
          "locale": {
            "format": "DD.MM.YYYY",
            "separator": " - ",
            "applyLabel": "Apply",
            "cancelLabel": "Cancel",
            "fromLabel": "From",
            "toLabel": "To",
            "customRangeLabel": "Custom",
            "weekLabel": "W",
            "daysOfWeek": [
```

Comment: That would be a big bunch of cookie.!!!!!! I want to get just the language name like 'en', 'fr' or others and then apply that in my javascript code.

Comment: You said you want to change language id according to the cookie. It means you already have some cookie. So you have to have the language definition of "Apply" and "Cancel".  Like this: {"key" : "_apply", "value" : "Apply", "lng" : "en"}  Off course you can save these two definitions in various ways. Cookie is just one of them.   Normally Datepickers have locales folders but unfortunately Daterangepicker has not. In that case you have to import external locale file in your project. That is also a traffic for your app.